# Storing Data to two dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have been working with a java, and wanted to Store the data in 2-d Array 12x2,
Below shown is the way to Store the data:
[image]

Below is the code for that i built,but unfortunately i am getting Exception

**`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`**

```
String[][] netswtich=new String[12][2];

for(int i =0;i<4;i++)
              {
                  for(int j=4;j>0;j--)
                  {
                        if(i==j) 
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        netswtich[k][0]=ranArray[i];
                        netswtich[k][1]=ranArray[j];
                        k++;
                  }
              }
```

Comment: I assume the problem is with ranArray[...]
You do not show what is inside ranArray and also not what the start value of k is...

Comment: It will cause exception because in your array you have used size of array to 12 i.e. i will goo to 0-11 but for 2nd dimension you have used 2 i.e. j will go to 0-1 but you are comparing j==4

Comment: and how did you initialize ranArray? you might get an exception on ranArray[4]

Comment: K=0; and ranArray consist of 5 strings..

Comment: String[] ranArray = new String[4]

Comment: Thank you CodeMaker for refactoring my code....:)

Comment: Executing this for loop second time show Exception"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Answer (score 4):

My guess you are getting array out of bounds on ranArray if the size of the vector is 4 you should start j from 3 to 0 `for(int j=3;j>=0;j--)`

Answer (score 0):

This means that you want to access an array element which isnt there, e.g. you want to access ranArray[4] while ranArray only holds 4 (or less elements), which means that 3 is the last usable array element.

Comment: but why can't it hold 5 elements..i mean starting from 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: If you define it as "String[] ranArray=new String[4];" that means that it can hold four elements. But since we start counting at 0 and not 1, this means that 3 is actually the fourth (and as such, the last) element: ranArray[0] ranArray[1] ranArray[2] ranArray[3] are the four usable elements. If you need more, just change the 4 to a 5 (or whatever else you need) at the definition.